# How to connect Phantom wallet to a Flutter app using deep links?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links, phantom-wallet

I'm making a flutter mobile app where I want to connect the user to the Phantom wallet using the connect deep link and then set the `redirect_link` as a Firebase dynamic link for the app, however I am not getting a response from the Phantom wallet as a query parameters. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install *uni_links* and *url_luncher* pakage

add this intent to androidManifest

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
    <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />
  </intent-filter>
```

then create queryParameter like

```
 Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
  "dapp_encryption_public_key":
      base58.encode(Uint8List.fromList(keypair.publicKey)),
  "cluster": "devnet",
  "app_url": "https://google.com",
  "redirect_link":
      "app://flutterdapp?handleQuery=onConnect}",
};
```

then lunchUrl

```
final url =Uri(
  scheme: "https",
  host: "phantom.app",
  path: "/ul/v1/onConnect",
  queryParameters: queryParameters,
);

 launchUrl(
  url,
  mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
 );
```

and recive data from phantom like

```
StreamSubscription _sub;

 Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
 // ... check initialLink

// Attach a listener to the stream
_sub = linkStream.listen((String? link) {
  // Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct
}, onError: (err) {
  // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
});

// NOTE: Don't forget to call _sub.cancel() in dispose()
 }

 // ...
```

hope help you

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I actually figured this out earlier, and yes I agree with your method using uni links is right!!